# (function fn(){ ... })() not working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to incorporate some crazy callback-recursion combo into my Node.js app. After some research, I found a strange syntax to both declare and execute function in the same block. So I try this simple code to test the concept:

```js
(function hello() {
        console.log("Hello, world!");
    })();

hello();
```

I expect it to just put two `Hello, world!`'s in the console. One immediately after declaration and one for the `hello()` call. However, it just prints one and then throws an error saying `hello is not defined` at `hello()`.

Is there something I'm not getting here?

Comment: The point of that self-invoking function syntax is that it's *not* globally defined, so you can't invoke it afterward.

Comment: by wrapping it in `()` you created a new scope.  Your `hello` function doesn't exist when you call it outside the `()`

Comment: @deltree The parenthesis don't create a scope. It's just that there's no assignation

Comment: @David So, I have to call `hello()` recursively for this to work?

Comment: @starleaf1: Not sure what you think recursion has to do with this.  You're defining a function in an enclosed expression and then executing that function.  You can't call that function from outside that expression.  For "this to work" I guess we'd need to know what you're trying to do here.

Comment: @deltree — No. The parenthesis turn the function declaration into a function expression. They change the scope the *variable* `hello` is created in (from the current scope to the scope of the new function), but they don't create a new scope.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript function declaration syntax: var fn = function() {} vs function fn() {}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-function-declaration-syntax-var-fn-function-vs-function-fn)

Comment: Though this isn't an exact duplicate, the issue is pretty much covered in the function declaration vs. expression q/as, so made the connection.

Comment: @David What I meant was, if I want to call `hello()`, I have to do it from inside the declaration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A *named function expression* only creates a variable with the same name as itself **within** its own scope. This is useful if you need to call it recursively.

```
(function hello() {
    // "hello" exists as a variable only here, inside the function
    console.log("Hello, world!");
})();
```

You need a function declaration to create a matching variable in the same scope as the function is declared (and you can't immediately invoke a function declaration).

```js
function hello() {
  console.log("Hello, world!");
}

hello();
hello();
```